# Apache Solr - send JSON query request from Postman

Tags: solr, postman

I want to send request to **Solr** from **Postman**.(request body should be in JSON).

can someone help me finding how to configure request URL and request JSON?
[image]

This is the index I have created in solr and want to send request using word or name as a request parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query for a specific field of the solr index by passing it as `q` parameter like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/new_core/select?q=name:John
```

As json object the following should work:

```
{
    query: "name:John"
 }
```

The url for the json query would be `http://localhost:8983/solr/new_core/query`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for quick response. I have one more requirement. I want to send request like (return all words which are starting with bl ) - { query: "word:bl" } then the result should be all words which started with "bl".  how to write request for same?

Comment: Great ! Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, if your question is answered it would be nice if you would accept the answer :-)